# Meta minimum in c++

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to do a minimum find in c++ with template meta-programming:

```
template<int first,int...a>
struct min
{
    static const int value= sizeof...(a) && first>min<a...>::value ? 
                             min<a...>::value : 
                             first;
};
```

Which would be called like:

```
static const int eleven = min<42,97,11,59>::value;
```

However, I got *"wrong number of template arguments (0, should be 1 or more)"*. I guess the compiler is trying to instantiate `min<>` with no arguments, but why? `min<a...>` is called only when `sizeof...(a)` is nonzero.

Why do I get this error, and how do I fix it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to do this with a `constexpr` function for additional points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short-circuiting behavior of `&&` doesn't stop the compiler from evaluating both expressions. `min<a...>::value` still has to be well-formed. So when `a...` becomes empty you end up with an instantiation of `min<>`, for which no specialization has been defined.

You can fix this by specializing for a single parameter:

```c++
template <int a>
struct min<a>
{
    static const int value = a;
};
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with SCE. The template-id is actually contained in the condition itself.

Comment: @Columbo I assume the OP thought SCE would prevent the instantiation of `min<>`.

Answer (score 3):

The two branches are evaluated, you may use specialization to solve that:

```
template<int first, int...a>
struct min
{
    static const int value = (first > min<a...>::value) ? min<a...>::value : first;
};

template<int first>
struct min<first>
{
    static const int value = first;
};
```

Comment: But *why* does min<> get evaluated?

Comment: All code should be correct, you cannot have `false ? invalid_code : valid_code();` even if code is not executed.

Answer (score 1):

The recursive instantiation removes one argument at a time. It goes like this: `min<1, 2, 3>` compares `1` with something that requires `min<2, 3>`, which in turn instantiates `min<3>` to compare it with `2`. Now `min<3>` tries to instantiate `min<>` to compare with `3`, which obviously doesn't work.

Use a partial specialization.

```
template <int first,int...a>
struct min
{ /* […] */ };

template <int first>
struct min<first>
{
    static const int value = first;
};
```

In case you thought that the compiler does not instantiate a specialization if it's solely contained in an unevaluated branch: He has to, to verify that the expression is valid.

Comment: But *why* does min<> get evaluated?

Comment: @Dave Because it's in the **condition** of the conditional expression? And even if it wasn't, the compiler must instantiate the template to verify that the expression is valid. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Side note (not answering the instantiation of min<>). 
You might use constepr functions to evaluate template and non template parameters:

```
#include <iostream>

// Single Value
template <typename T>
inline constexpr const T&
min_of(const T& a) {
    return a;
}

// Multiple Values
template <typename T, typename ...Args>
inline constexpr const T&
min_of(const T& a, const T& b, const Args& ...args) {
    // std::min as constexpr is C++14
    return min_of((a < b) ? a : b, args...);
}

// Template Arguments
template <int A, int ... Other>
constexpr int min_of() {
    return min_of(A, Other...);
}


// Test
template <int Value>
void print() {
    std::cout << "   template: " << Value << '\n';
}

int main() {
    print<min_of<42,97,11,59>()>();
    std::cout << "no template: " << min_of(42,97,11,59) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```